# Ubuntu 16.04 from external HDD keeps freezing?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have an HP Laptop, with an internal HDD running Windows7 Pro. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an external HDD.
I dual-boot with this HDD, launch Ubuntu, and it all works fine, for a while.
After a certain amount of time - which appears to be random - the OS (Ubuntu) simply freezes.
It acts as if, I have forcefully unplugged the external HDD (which is not the case): desktop shortcuts are no longer showing their right icons, sometimes, icons are removed completely; keyboard shortcuts are no longer working.
If I shut down -> boot Ubuntu again, it works fine, again, for a while.

I have tried to plug the external HDD in a different USB slot, but it does not help.

Has anyone had such issues before? is it the Ubuntu version that's a problem, or the external HDD has some issues?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You must inspect your `syslog` file. Take note when freezing happens, so you can open `/var/log/syslog` and see at that very time what messages you have.

Comment: Is this a 1TB or larger external HDD? Does it have its own power brick (or an option to add one?)? Does the cable to the HDD have two USB plugs on the computer end of the cable?

Comment: @heynnema 120gb SSD, without auxiliary power. Do you think it could be a power surge issue?

Comment: @nightfixed not if it's only a 120G SSD. What I WOULD check is the firmware in the SSD. Go to the manufacturer's web site with the model # and check. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema it's a Kingston SUV400. I checked on their website, and there is no option to "firmware update" for this model, so I suppose, the firmware version is the latest? also, I paid some attention to when these freezes are happening, and it's more frequent when I am using Skype or Facebook messenger, making calls. I tried to check the `syslog` as suggested above, but the log that I get after the pc reboot, starts at the reboot - so the lines with the freeze I don't have.

Comment: At https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ssdmanager there's a Windows app SSD Manager, which will check/update the firmware.

Comment: im experiencing exaclty the same issue.
Did you get to find out finally what was the problem or how to solve it ?
lg Demna

Comment: @Vitjo no, I ended up using a different version of Linux (mint) and a different SSD.